# Unable to encrypt special characters: not multiple of block length

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have an encryption/decryption algorithm and I'm trying to encrypt some special characters to send to the server from android, but it is throwing an exception:

> java.lang.Exception: [encrypt] error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length

Normal Latin characters are encrypted/decrypted fine, but special characters aren't.

Here is my code:

```
public class MCrypt {

    private String iv = "fedcba9876543210";//Dummy iv (CHANGE IT!)
    private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
    private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
    private Cipher cipher;

    private String SecretKey = "0123456789abcdef";//Dummy secretKey (CHANGE IT!)

    public MCrypt()
    {
        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception
    {
        //if(text == null || text.length() == 0)
        //  throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] encrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {                       
            throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return encrypted;
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception
    {
        if(code == null || code.length() == 0)
            throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] decrypted = null;

        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data==null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int len = data.length;
        String str = "";
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16)
                str = str + "0" + Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
            else
                str = str + Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
            }
        return str;
    }

    public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
        if (str==null) {
            return null;
        } else if (str.length() < 2) {
            return null;
        } else {
            int len = str.length() / 2;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }

    private static String padString(String source)
    {
        char paddingChar = ' ';
        int size = 32;
        int x = source.length() % size;
        int padLength = size - x;

        for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)
        {
            source += paddingChar;
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem here is?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [When encrypting data that is not an even multiple of the block size do I have to send a complete last block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845706/when-encrypting-data-that-is-not-an-even-multiple-of-the-block-size-do-i-have-to)

Comment: your error message points to this duplicate.

Comment: I see the resemblance but it does not offer a solution as to how my problem with special characters can be resolved

Comment: the thing is that you are padding the string to be a multiple of 32, but then you get the bytes, which can be 1,2,3 or 4 for each character (default encoding in android should be utf-8), messing with your padded length. you need to pad the byte[] once it is extracted from the string.

Comment: Note that mcrypt (for PHP) itself pads zero's until the first block boundary is reached (0 to 15 bytes with value `'\0'`). Furthermore, it may use RIJNDAEL_256 with is not AES at all (you seem to have a block size of 32 bytes). I got *horrible* code in Java when I tried to replicate the **completely braindead** implementation of mcrypt.

Comment: Yes it has been a pain. Can you recommend a better one?

Answer (score 7):

Change this line:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
```

To

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this Blog](https://androidfreetutorial.wordpress.com/2017/03/14/android-encryptiondecryption-with-aes-algorithm/)

Change this line :

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding"); //this may be not decrypt full plaintext.
```

To:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding"); // use this for descrypt full plain text without lost.
```