# Error in encrypting data

Tags: android, encryption

Trying to encrpt and decrypt data by the following code :

```
    public class MCrypt {


   // private String iv = "";
    private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
    private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
    private Cipher cipher;

    //private String SecretKey = "";
Context context;
    public MCrypt(Context context)
    {
        this.context=context;
        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(context.getString(R.string.iv).getBytes());
        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(context.getString(R.string.secretkey).getBytes(), "AES");
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public MCrypt(Context context, String key)
    {
        this.context=context;
        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(context.getString(R.string.iv).getBytes());

        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");

        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String encrypt(String text) throws Exception
    {
        if(text == null || text.length() == 0)
            throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] encrypted = null;

        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return bytesToHex(encrypted);
    }

    public String decrypt(String code) throws Exception
    {
        if(code == null || code.length() == 0)
            throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] decrypted = null;

        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return Html.fromHtml(new String(decrypted)).toString().trim();
    }



    public String bytesToHex(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data==null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int len = data.length;
        String str = "";
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16)
                str = str + "0" + Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
            else
                str = str + Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
        }
        return str;
    }


    public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
        if (str==null) {
            return null;
        } else if (str.length() < 2) {
            return null;
        } else {
            int len = str.length() / 2;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }



    private static String padString(String source)
    {
        char paddingChar = ' ';
        int size = 16;
        int x = source.length() % size;
        int padLength = size - x;

        for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)
        {
            source += paddingChar;
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

Now when I use few strings it work like a charm. But now suddenly it stopped working for a large string with this error :

```
   java.lang.Exception: [encrypt] error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length
12-18 15:32:42.057 21834-22054/com.app.aspire_pd W/System.err:     at com.app.aspire_pd.Other.MCrypt.encrypt(MCrypt.java:75)
12-18 15:32:42.057 21834-22054/com.app.aspire_pd W/System.err:     at com.app.aspire_pd.AsyncTask.APIHit.HitAPI(APIHit.java:320)
12-18 15:32:42.057 21834-22054/com.app.aspire_pd W/System.err:     at com.app.aspire_pd.AsyncTask.HitAPI.doInBackground(HitAPI.java:98)
12-18 15:32:42.057 21834-22054/com.app.aspire_pd W/System.err:     at com.app.aspire_pd.AsyncTask.HitAPI.doInBackground(HitAPI.java:24)
12-18 15:32:42.057 21834-22054/com.app.aspire_pd W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
12-18 15:32:42.057 21834-22054/com.app.aspire_pd W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-18 15:32:42.057 21834-22054/com.app.aspire_pd W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-18 15:32:42.057 21834-22054/com.app.aspire_pd W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-18 15:32:42.057 21834-22054/com.app.aspire_pd W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-18 15:32:42.057 21834-22054/com.app.aspire_pd W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34320152/5327912) to change my encrption line to

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

but that is **not** working.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

`cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");`

to

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding","SC");
```

Comment: getting error as : java.security.NoSuchProviderException: Provider not available: SC

Comment: Have you add in your gradle file to following dependencies:-"compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.54.0.0'" and "  compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.54.0.0'"

Comment: getting this error now : CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled. Installation campaign tracking is not possible.

Comment: Put a static block in your java code and add following line of code:                       static {
        Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
    }